# Rails Development Server Reading Wrong Requests "Started Get '/'..." when I am not even hitting '/'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I am in the middle of debugging a very slow admin page in my application right now. When I was reading the logs, it seemed that there was possibly an *N + 1* query going on:

```
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079887 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079805 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079744 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079910 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079875 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079898 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079916 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079918 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079783 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079751 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079921 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079911 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079785 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079770 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079908 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079760 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079827 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079919 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079882 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079690 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079933 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079915 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079707 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079906 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079892 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079801 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079913 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079900 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079947 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079769 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079964 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079765 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079967 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079926 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079927 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079950 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079979 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079981 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079980 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079814 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079931 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079986 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079988 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079997 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079957 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079830 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079822 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079806 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079714 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079946 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079896 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079851 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079971 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079863 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079905 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079914 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079941 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079848 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079953 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511080019 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079834 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079907 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079934 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079951 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511080004 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511080021 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079929 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079973 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079961 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079928 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511080027 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079904 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079962 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079965 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079855 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079877 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079841 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079816 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511080040 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079932 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511080039 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079860 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511080047 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079985 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079878 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079826 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079945 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511080038 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079954 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511080017 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079999 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079808 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079766 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511080060 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079955 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079987 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079983 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511080008 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511080032 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511080073 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079829 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511080080 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079976 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511080046 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511080003 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511080071 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079940 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079780 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511080034 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511080091 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511080072 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079695 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511080056 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079694 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079833 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511080090 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511079803 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511080067 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 511080098 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `units`.* FROM
```

With **dozens** of more lines like this.

As I began investigating, I deleted everything in my view and the correspongding controller action.

> routes.rb

```
  # ... many other routes
  # The route causing problems  
  get '/admin/unit/:id/data/:days', to: 'admins#unit_data', as: 'unit_data'

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'units#root_unit'
```

> admins_controller.rb

```
def unit_data
  puts "Hello World!"
end
```

```
...
Hello World
  Rendered admins/unit_data.html.erb within layouts/new_application (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/new_application.html.erb (35.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 744ms (Views: 45.1ms | ActiveRecord: 554.4ms)
```

Everything looks good so far and it loads my blank `.erb` page, **but after, it for some reason does a request to root**

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2019-04-18 09:44:39 -0400
Processing by UnitsController#root_unit as */*
```

I checked for before filters, but they are not realted to this. Could this be a potential  reason why this page is super slow? We are trying to optimize for large amounts of data displayed on graphs... I am pretty sure this has nothing to with extremely long load times, but I still want to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: you mean after rendering admins/unit_data.html.erb page, server automatically redirects it to root_url?

Comment: That's what the logs say, but the page doesn't take you anywhere else. You still stay on that blank page.

Comment: Are you sure no js code is making an ajax request of some kind? Also turbolinks may be trying to "help" you with this as well.

Comment: Could your layout file have something which make a request to `/`? Try opening the network tab in developer tools of your browser and see if your page is sending request to "/" or if it originates from some place else.

Answer (score 0):

When debugging individual requests - `curl` is your friend, because modern browsers by default have page prediction which can trigger additional ones, that you're not anticipating at the moment.

If page requires authentication - you can "copy as cURL" in devtools with all cookies etc. and request page from console. This way you can be sure the request is the only running (browser can be even closed at the moment)